# In Python how remove extra space elements from two dimensional array?

Tags: python-3.4

For eg.

```
list = [['2', '2', '', ''], ['3', '3', '', ''], ['4', '4', '', '']]
```

and i want as

```
newlist = [['2','2'],['3','3'],['4','4']]
```

is there any list comprehensive compact way to achieve this
like for 1D array we have `[x for x in strings if x]` is there any thing similar to this.

Comment: Something like `[list(s for s in list_of_strings if s) for list_of_strings in list_of_lists_of_strings]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean you wish to remove empty elements fromm your 2darray. If that is the case then:

```
old_list = [['2', '2', '', ''], ['3', '3', '', ''], ['4', '4', '', '']]
new_list = [[instance for instance in sublist if len(instance)>0] for sublist in old_list]
```

If you wish to remove elements containing only whitespace(spaces etc), then yoy may do something like:

```
old_list = [['2', '2', '', ''], ['3', '3', '', ''], ['4', '4', '', '']]
new_list = [[instance for instance in sublist if not instance.isspace()] for sublist in old_list]
```

Answer (score 2):

`list = [[x for x in y if x != ''] for y in list]`

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you are posting answers please explain what you have written as well. Code only answer are not the best and can be flagged as low quality answer.

Comment: @Syfer Oh, I thought it was self explanatory, but thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [filter](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#filter). Also unrelated but since `list` is a reserved word it's best not to use it and try to come up with a more meaningful name, I've simply renamed it to original_list since the `list()` method won't work otherwise.

```
original_list = [['2', '2', '', ''], ['3', '3', '', ''], ['4', '4', '', '']]
new_list = []
for sub_list in original_list:
    new_sub_list = list(filter(None, sub_list))
    new_list.append(new_sub_list)

print(new_list)
```

Or in short

```
new_list2 = [ list(filter(None, sub_list)) for sub_list in original_list ]
print(new_list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this list comprehension:

```
list = [[x for x in a if x] for a in list]
```